# Gutenberg InnerBlocks Does Not Save

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

Need help with custom WP Block.  The block allows user to add an image, text, and ability to have inner blocks to include rich content.

While everything saves and works, the InnerBlocks content is lost upon refresh.  Additionally, the InnberBlocks does not render on front end.

This is the JS:

```
 wp.blocks.registerBlockType('gpe/media-text', {
            apiVersion: 2,
    title: 'Media-Text',        // Block name visible to the user within the editor
    icon: 'warning',    // Toolbar icon displayed beneath the name of the block
    category: 'common', // The category under which the block will appear in the Add block menu
    attributes: {           // The data this block will be storing
        image_id : { type : 'number', default : -1 },
        image_name : { type : 'string', default: ""},
        image_url: { type: 'string' , selector : 'sc-media-upload-image'},          // Notice box type for loading the appropriate CSS class. Default class is 'default'.
        image_text: { type: 'string' },
        text_content: { type: 'string' },           // Title of Notice box in h4 tag
        inner_content : { type: 'string'},
    },
    edit:  function(props) {
        // Defines how the block will render in the editor
         //const [ isChecked, setChecked ] = useState( true )

        return el( 'div', 
            useBlockProps ({ 
                className: 'media-text' ,
                style : {

                }
            }), 
            el(     InnerBlocks , {  onChange : function(a){console.error(a); } }  ) ,
            el(
                TextControl , 
                ({ 
                    //type: 'text', 
                    placeholder: 'Section title',
                    value: props.attributes.text_content,
                    onChange: (value) => { 
                         props.setAttributes({  text_content: value }) 
                    },
                    style: { 
                         
                    }
                })
            ),
            el (MediaUpload , 
                { 
                    value: props.attributes.image_url,
                    allowedTypes: ['images'],
                    labels: { title : 'Select Feature Image' },
                    multiple: false, 
                    onSelect: function(media){
                        console.error ("DEBUG>>", media, "Attributes", props.attributes);
                        props.setAttributes({
                            image_url: media.url,
                            image_name : media.filename,
                            image_text : media.title
                        }) 
                    },
                    render: function  ({ open }){
                        return el("div",{},
                            el ('img', { src : props.attributes.image_url , width: 200+'px', height: '200px' , onClick : open })
                            )
                    }
                }
            ),
                
            

        );  // End return

    },  // End edit()
    save: function(props) {
        return null;
    }   // End save()
});
```

This is the render_callback:

```
    register_block_type( 'gpe/media-text', array(
    'render_callback' => 'jst_block_media_text_render',
    'api_version' => 2,
    'editor_script' => 'slb-script',    //this name must match with wp_register_script - script name
    'editor_style' => 'slb-style',
) );

function jst_block_media_text_render ( $attr, $content ) {


$out = '<div class="flex media-text gpe">' .
            '<img src="'. $attr['image_url'] . '">'. 
            '<div class="content">'.
                $content .
            ' - content </div>'.
        '</div>'  ;

return $out;
```

}

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you manage to solve the probleme?

Comment: unfortunately i have not received an answer and have not figured it out yet

Comment: I rewrote my custom block from scratch, and now it is working. But I can‘t tell you what changed exactly (yeah!)

Comment: could you post a the working version, or the relevant pieces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you will find a working solution. I have stripped out any non-relevant things. Please note that this posted code is not tested.

```
import {InnerBlocks, useBlockProps} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import {registerBlockType} from '@wordpress/blocks';

registerBlockType('urukai/example', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: 'An Example Block',
    category: 'common',
    description: 'An example block with inner blocks',
    icon: 'carrot',
    edit() {

        const p = useBlockProps({
            className: 'u-block u-example-block'
        });

        return (
            <div {...p}>
                <div className="text-content-container">
                    <InnerBlocks
                        allowedBlocks={ [ 'core/heading', 'core/paragraph', 'core/list' ] }
                        template={ [
                            [ 'core/heading', { placeholder: 'Example Title...' } ],
                            [ 'core/paragraph', { placeholder: 'Examplte text goes here...' } ]
                        ]}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
    save() {
        return <div className="your-container-class"><InnerBlocks.Content/></div>;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @uruk.  While it does not address the specific use case I originally wanted(server side render), it does conform to me that rendering on PHP with InnerBlocks does not work.  The closest I found was https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/26384#issuecomment-714853854 which says there is a third parameter to your render function.  However, I tried it and it does not have any innerblocks content that could be rendered on front end.  All-round frustrating.  But, thank you sooo much for your time and answer!

Comment: You can render the inner blocks by filtering the `render_block`-hook. Then you have the full block-array and iterate over each inner block.

Comment: So  I use an "add_filter" hook or you mean look like  foreach ( $block->inner_blocks as $inner_block )?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly, and then render the default blocks (or the ones you're not interested in) with `render_block( $block )`, and the one you're interested in with your custom method.